# React-Redux action not taking effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to change the store of redux when an input has been changed.
I have my input with the property on change as it follows:

> ```
>  onChange= {(event, value) => {
>         if(value) {
>             addCountry(value)
>             console.log(countries)
>           }
> ```

countries, (the one im console loggin), is what I want to be changed when I dispatch addCountry with its value.

The addCountry action is this one:

```
export function addCountry(name) {
  return {type: 'ADD_COUNTRY', payload: name }
}
```

And my reducer works like this:

```
const initialState = {
  countries: ['World'],
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  
  if(action.type === 'ADD_COUNTRY'){
    return {
      ...state,
      countries: [...state.countries, action.payload]
    }
  }

}

export default rootReducer;
```

I dont understand, everytime I change the input, and then console.log(countries) as showed before, it console logs the same, as if it was working asynchronously, but I understand redux works synchronously.

If you are worried im not connecting my component to the store as I should let me show you im doing it right:

```
// MapStateToProps for access to specific items of the store-state
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    countries: state.countries,
  };
}

// MapDispatchToProps to directly dispatch an action when called in this component
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addCountry: (name) => dispatch(addCountry(name)),
  };
}

// Connects the Component with the store
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CountrySelect);
```

Im trying to display a chart with the info of countries, if countries does not change , neither does my chart, so I need to solve this.

Comment: I added the reducer to the root reducer in the store if you were wondering.

Comment: I would debug by adding console logs to each function and see how far you're actually getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I understand redux works synchronously.

Sort of.  It's not using promises, but it's still React, which means `countries` won't be updated until the next render.

Since you are using hooks, you probably want it to look like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(countries);
}, [countries]);
```

If you still don't get a `console.log`, then you need to figure out where it's failing.  I would do:

```
export function addCountry(name) {
    console.log('ADD_COUNTRY payload created with ' + name);
    return {type: 'ADD_COUNTRY', payload: name }
}

// MapDispatchToProps to directly dispatch an action when called in this component
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addCountry: (name) => {
            console.log('addCountry dispatched');
            dispatch(addCountry(name)),
        }
    }
}

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if(action.type === 'ADD_COUNTRY'){
        console.log('ADD_COUNTRY state updating')
        return {
            ...state,
            countries: [...state.countries, action.payload]
        }
    }
}

 onChange= {(event, value) => {
     console.log('onChange called');
     if(value) {
         console.log('onChange if');
         addCountry(value)
         console.log(countries)
     }
 }
```

and figure out where the breakdown is.

Comment: I havent added the props before because I deconstruct it like this: {countries} mm it probably has to do with that thing you said countries won't be updated until the next render. So how could i solve this?

Comment: In that case, there might not be anything to fix - it should rerender, you just can't log the new value there.  Are you using hooks or react classes?

Comment: hooks, but the thing is that i have a chart being rendered at another component, and it should change everytime countries changes, and it doesnt

Comment: what do you mean when you say countries won't be updated until the next render?  until the next render of what exactly?

Comment: Of the component.  Every time your component receives new props, it will rerender it.  So when you `dispatch` something, it will still be "asynchronous".  Or if you use `const [thing, setThing] = useState()`, for example, you can't do `setThing('foo'); console.log(thing)` - you'll still get `undefined` until the next render.

Comment: I do have a useEffect hook with the dependency of countries at the component that uses it (my chart) . However my chart is not updating with the new value? what im i doing wrong, i feel like im missing something

Comment: I did it, and the one at the root reducer ( console.log('ADD_COUNTRY state updating')) is not being showed! why wouldnt? the action types are the same, that should not be the issue

Comment: Now you get to debug, add `console.log(action)` right before `if(action.type === 'ADD_COUNTRY'){`

Comment: nothing returned as well, it seems like my reducer is not working

Comment: Did you do this? https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store

Comment: Yes I have the provider at my app.js containig everything and i created the store as well

Comment: I wasnt bringing the addCountry to the component as a prop, that was it all, sorry for being that stupid!

Comment: so literally the first thing I said was probably the problem and you said you were destructuring it from props...

Comment: i was destructuring countries, but not addCountries,